# Highcharts export server startExport is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts-export-server: 3.0.0-beta.1 , to avoid PhantomJs.
I'm using an express node server.

This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "expresspdftest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "export <setting>=<value>",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base64-img": "^1.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.1",
    "highcharts-export-server": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.54",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

This is where I call highcharts export server :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require("path");
var request = require("request");
const exporter = import('highcharts-export-server');
//DON'T WORRY, OTHER IMPORTS ARE CORRECTLY DONE

var fineco,graphic,rating,graphicB64,dd,riskComponent,today,negComponent,graphicComponent,errorMessage,graphicTitle;

logs.info('Logging Started..');
function createPdfBinary(pdfDoc, callback) 
{
  var fonts = 
  {
    Roboto: 
    {
      normal: path.join(__dirname,'..','public','fonts','Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
      bold: path.join(__dirname,'..','public','fonts','Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
      italics: path.join(__dirname,'..','public','fonts','Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
      bolditalics: path.join(__dirname,'..','public','fonts','Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf')
    }
  };

  var printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fonts);

  var doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfDoc);  
  var chunks = [];
  var result;

  doc.on('data', function (chunk) 
  {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });
  doc.on('end', function () 
  {
    result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    callback(result);  
  });
  doc.end();
}

/* GET pdf. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) 
{
  var Code = req.query.id;
  var URL = appConfig.fidaxServiceUrl;
  request(URL+Code,function(error,response,body)
  {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      var inputData = JSON.parse(body);
      if (inputData != null || inputData != undefined)
      {
        var checkedData = modelValidator.validator(inputData);
        var counterSott = 0, counterComment = 0;
        fineco = logoEncoder.base64Sync(path.join(__dirname,"..","public","images","logo_Fineco.png"));
        if(checkedData.Underlying != null || checkedData.Underlying != undefined ) counterSott = checkedData.Underlying.length;
        if(inputData.AnnualCouponRates != null && inputData.AnnualCouponRates !=undefined && inputData.AnnualCouponRates != NaN && inputData.AnnualCouponRates != "NaN") counterComment = checkedData.AnnualCouponRates.length;
        graphic = graphicConstructor.createChart(checkedData.HistoricalData);
        today= dataMaker.getToday();
        Highcharts(graphic);
      }
      else
      {
        logs.info("Dati in ingresso non validi "+" | Fida Code : "+Code);
        res.send(response);
      }
    }else if (error)
    {
      logs.info(error.code+" | Fida Code : "+Code);
      res.send(error.code);
    }
    else
    {
      errorMessage = "FIDA Code non valido.";
      try
      {
        var errRes = JSON.parse(body);
        errorMessage = errRes.Message;
      } catch(e){}
      logs.info(errorMessage+" | Fida Code : "+Code);      
      res.send(errorMessage);
    }
  });
});

async function Highcharts()
{
  console.log(exporter);
  console.log(typeof exporter);
  await exporter.initPool();
  exporter.startExport(graphic, function(err,exp)
  {
    if(err == false)
    {
      graphicB64 = exp.data;
      graphicB64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+graphicB64;
      switch(checkedData.Type)
      {
          case "OBB": rating = getRating.getRatingCell(checkedData.RatingSandP);
                      ratingData = getRating.getRatingData(checkedData.DataRatingSandP);
                      graphicComponent = getGraphicObb.getGraphicTable(graphicB64,counterComment);
                      graphicTitle = getGraphicTitle.getTitle(counterComment);
                      dd = obbPDF.Obbligazione(fineco,ratingData,rating,graphicComponent,checkedData,today,graphicTitle,Code); 
                      break;
          case "CER": riskComponent = getRisk.riskTable(checkedData.RiskGrade);
                      underlyingComponent = getUnderlying.underlyingTable(checkedData.Underlying);
                      informationTitle = getInfo.getInfoNeg(counterSott);
                      negComponent = getInfo.getInfoTable(counterSott,checkedData);
                      graphicComponent = getGraphicCert.getGraphicTable(graphicB64,counterSott);
                      dd = certPDF.Certificato(fineco,riskComponent,graphicComponent,underlyingComponent,informationTitle,negComponent,checkedData,today); 
                      break;
      }
      exporter.killPool();
      createPdfBinary(dd, function(binary) 
      {
        logs.info("PDF Creato - Fida Code :"+Code);
        res.contentType('application/pdf');
        res.send(binary);
      });
    }        
    else
    {
      exporter.killPool();
      logs.info(err+" | Fida Code : "+Code);
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = router;
```

I get this error when I run my server :
TypeError: exporter.startExport is not a function

Can you help me, pls?

I expect it works like old version (can't use old version cause of PhantomJs is not maintained anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this might be the following:

- the current documentation on the `enhancement/puppeteer` branch reflects what works in the latest beta version ([3.0.0-beta.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-export-server/v/3.0.0-beta.2))
- a simple usage of the *Export Server* as a node module was introduced in beta.2 (here's a [pull request](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/pull/408))

I believe that updating to `3.0.0-beta.2` should solve it. If not, please let me know or create a new issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server) and it will be investigated.

PS. It's also worth keeping in mind that `error` is now the second argument passed to the `startExport` callback whereas the `response` is the first (different order than in your attached code).

Comment: Hi Jakub.
Thanks for your answer.

I solved just by transforming all  < var x = require("y") > in module imports.
I also swapped error and response after I fixed the main problem.

Comment: Great, I'm happy that you've solved it. Do not hesitate to report any issues you encounter on our GH: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server